# More efficient way to write to a file

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

I am currently transferring a file from a c++ server using the following c# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace WebRequestTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Making small binary request: 1MB");
            makeRequest("http://server:8081/sm_binary", "sm_copied");

            Console.WriteLine("Making medium binary request: 10MB");
            makeRequest("http://server:8081/md_binary", "md_copied");

            Console.WriteLine("Making large binary request: 100MB");
            makeRequest("http://server:8081/lg_binary", "lg_copied");

            Console.WriteLine("Making huge binary request: 2GB");
            makeRequest("http://server:8081/hg_binary", "hg_copied");


            while (true) { }
        }

        static void makeRequest(string url, string filename)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting request: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss-fff"));
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();

            Console.WriteLine("Starting file write: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss-fff"));
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create("./Binaries/" + filename))
            {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                fs.Close();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Process is done: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH-mm-ss-fff") + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting reasonable times on the first three file transfers, with the 100MB transfer and write taking about 43 seconds. The 2GB file transfer is taking obnoxiously long at about 37 minutes compared to the expected ~15 minutes. I would like to make sure that the receiving side of this code is not causing the slowdown and I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to write these files to disk.

Comment: First, remove the `while (true) { }`...

Comment: That only exists to keep the console open, it has no effect on the transfer

Comment: Woudln't `Stream.CopyTo` be more efficient than reading / writing bytes?

Comment: I know, but it is bad practice. Use `Console.ReadLine()` instead.

Comment: Some multithreading would help too...

Comment: Also if you want to know where the slowdown is why don't you try to check how much time it takes to download the file itself, before any writing is done?

Comment: How would I do that Crono, that is something I have been trying to figure out how to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try using the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx) class instead to obtain the raw file rather than a streamed block:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(fileUri, filePathOnHardDrive);
```

Comment: That code is already there, but I have encountered if I close the server when the file is writing then the c# code throws an exception. This leads me to believe that the file is being streamed from the server instead of being sent as a block.

Comment: @JME - Do you really want to try and keep a 2GB file in memory before writing any of it?

Comment: For testing purposes possibly

Comment: @JME Why would you test a solution that is bad anyway? Write a good solution and then test that.

Comment: @Ashigore he probably meant checking downloaded data content.